# Make my proof that $\mathcal S (\mathbb R^n) \;is\; L^{\infty}$-dense in $C_0(\mathbb R^n)$ rigorous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

In our definition,

$C_0(\mathbb R^n) =\left\{f\in C(\mathbb R^n):\ \lim_{x\to\infty} |f(x)| = 0\right\},$ and

$\mathcal S (\mathbb R^n) $ is just the Schwarz space.

What I want to show is that $\mathcal S (\mathbb R^n)$ is $L^{\infty}$-dense in $C_0(\mathbb R^n).$

Let $\varepsilon\gt 0$, and $f \in C_0(\mathbb R^n).$

Firstly, we find a large $r \in \mathbb R^{+}$ s.t.  $|f| \lt \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ outside the closed ball $B_r(0).$ Then $|f|\lt \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ outside the closed balls $B_{r+1}(0)$ and $B_{r+2}(0).$ I try to define a function $g$ s.t. $\Vert f -g \Vert_{\infty} \lt \varepsilon.$

Let $g = f$ on the closed ball $B_{r+1}(0),$ and let $g = 0$ outside the closed ball $B_{r+2}(0).$ And I extend $g$ smoothly between these two balls, i.e. the annulus between $B_{r+1}(0)$ and $B_{r+2}(0).$ The function $g$ defined in such way will clearly belong to $\mathcal S (\mathbb R^n) $ and satisfies $\Vert f -g \Vert_{\infty} \lt \varepsilon.$

My problem is that, can someone make the process which make $g$ smooth between two balls rigorous? I think this process can always be done(the smoothness like the graph of the bump function), but I can't give an explicit smoothness or prove the existence of this process. Rigorousness just means that to prove the existence of this process. Can someone give me a hint or proof?

Thank you so much in advance.

————————————————————

The solution to my problem can be found in the comments, due to the work of Daniel.

Comment: Are you familar(-ish) with convolutions?

Comment: @DanielFischer I know convolution but not too much. I can try to find the proposition which you are going to use.

Comment: Multiply $f$ with a continuous cut-off function to get a continuous function with compact support within $\varepsilon/2$ from $f$. Convolve the compact-support function with a smooth bump function [with total mass $1$] to get a smooth function with compact support close to $f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I have looked up in google and wiki, and I found the proposition you use seems needing the knowledge of distribution theory, but I have not learned yet. I can roughly understand your thought, but I still don’t know what is cut-off function. Can we smooth g(defined as in my description of question) directly using your method? i.e. convolve g with a smooth bump function to get a smooth function? Thanks.

Comment: Distribution theory isn't needed. That the convolution of two functions with compact support [its existence assumed, so the functions must not be too wild, continuity is far more than needed] has compact support is easily seen from the definition of the convolution. That the convolution of a smooth function with compact support and a not too badly behaved function is smooth follows with the dominated convergence theorem by differentiation under the integral. If the other function is also continuous, that's also easy to prove if one uses the Riemann integral.

Comment: A cut-off function is a continuous (or smooth, depending on the setting) function with values in $[0,1]$ that is $1$ on the set $A$ of interest (that's $B_{r+1}(0)$ in your case) and $0$ outside some specified (preferably relatively compact) neighbourhood of $A$ ($B_{r+2}(0)$ for your approach). Multiplying $f$ with such a cut-off function gives you a continuous $g$ that coincides with $f$ on $B_{r+1}(0)$ and has support in $B_{r+2}(0)$. Then convolving with a bump function gives a smooth function with compact support,

Comment: and if the bump function has total mass $1$ and support in a small neighbourhood of $0$, the convolution is very close to $g$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I understand your method completely now. Thank you so much Daniel. But I still have a small question. I can understand your last words [i.e. if the bump function has total mass $1$ and support in a small neighborhood of $0$, the convolution is very close to $g$] intuitively, but I don’t want to just “feel” it. So could you give me link of proof or proof about this words? I just learned the definition about convolution, and some very basic property such as the convolution operator commutes etc. So I am not lazy... I really want a proof about this. Thank you so so much.

Comment: I'm too lazy to write a proof now. But if $\varphi$ vanishes for $\lVert x\rVert > \delta$, then $(g\ast \varphi)(x)$ is a weighted average of the values of $g$ on $B_{\delta}(x)$, and thus differs from $g(x)$ by at most $\omega_{g,x}(\delta) = \sup \{ \lvert g(x) - g(y)\rvert : y\in B_{\delta}(x)\}$ (assuming $\varphi \geqslant 0$, multiply with $\int \lvert \varphi\rvert$ otherwise). Since $g$ is uniformly continuous (by the compact support), $\omega_g(\delta) = \sup \{\omega_{g,x}(\delta) : x \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$ is finite and tends to $0$ for $\delta \to 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Haha, actually what you wrote was a proof. I understand it now. Thank you Daniel :)